# Eclipse Error when inserting Admob Ad Unit ID

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

Why does eclispe think that my Ad Unit ID is an error?
I haven't added a full source code, because I think that it's not needed.. If someone wants it, tell me!
Here's a screenshot:[image]

Comment: That should be a string and you forgot the double quote (")... learn more about data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your ad-id in quotation marks, like

```
"my-ad-unit-id"
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked.. (I really need to learn java and stop fooling around :( )